# Is this use of "more and more" before and gerund after the expression "drowning himself into" acceptable?

Tags: word-in-context

> He has been more and more drowning himself into drinking.

Does this phrase make any sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but it's a bit clunky (and ***into drinking*** is completely non-idiomatic here). Better would be *He has **increasingly** been drowning himself **in drink***. Note that in general, ***more and more*** works better with ***adjectives***, not verb forms. For example, ***He became more and more angry***.

Comment: When used with a verb it usually follows right after, e.g. *he drank more and more and eventually slid under the table, where Jack was already lying comatose*, or *I don't know what to do - he just goes on drinking more and more*. *Drowning himself in drink* is OK, as FumbleFingers has said, but I think you may be thinking of *drowning his sorrows*.

Comment: Thanks a milllion, FumbleFingers and Minty, for the explanations and all amazing tips. Minty, I was thinking of he drowning himself (figuratively, of course), not his sorrows, in drink. Despite of that, until  now I didn't know about the expression "drowning his sorrows" in English, so I'll consider it as a bonus. Thanks again.